# Redraw Awesomium surface

Tags: c#, awesomium

When I change form `ShowInTaskbar` property, a new handle is created and `webview(awesomium)` is now somehow empty. Is there any way to restore the previous state?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

When this bug occurs, it can be fixed by providing webview a **new** handle.

```
this.Controls.Remove(webPanel);
webPanel = new Panel();
this.Controls.Add(webPanel);
webView.ParentWindow = webPanel.Handle;
resize();
return;
```